# Apps Script API response has no "result" key

Tags: c#, .net, google-apps-script, google-api-dotnet-client, google-apps-script-api

I created a Google Apps Script project to upload files to Google Drive, and built an app in C# to execute this script. I used the sample code given in the [documentation's guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#api_request_examples)

However, when I call my function via the Apps Script API, my C# app raises the following exception:

> `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

when executing this line:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject folderSet = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)op.Response["result"];
```

This is the relevant setup code:

```
  ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest();
  request.Function = "uploadDocument";
  IList<Object> prms = new List<Object>();
  prms.Add(name.ToString());
  prms.Add(dest);
  prms.Add(file);
  request.Parameters = prms;
  ScriptsResource.RunRequest runReq =
      service.Scripts.Run(request, scriptId);
  try
  {
      // Make the API request.
      Operation op = runReq.Execute();

      if (op.Error != null)
      {
          IDictionary<string, object> error = op.Error.Details[0];
          Console.WriteLine("Script error message: {0}", error["errorMessage"]);
      }
      else
      {
          Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject folderSet =
              (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)op.Response["result"];
          Console.WriteLine("ok");
      }
  }
```

If i change "result" to "@type" this error is displayed

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.'

Comment: Try Lowercase `r` in `response` and `e` in `error` or `(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)op["response"]["result"]`

Comment: Show your Apps Script function. Does it have a return value?

Comment: Hi, yeah this is my return:

return JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL, options));

Comment: Hi, i cant set lowercase r in response. An error is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your Google App Script function doesn't have a return statement. The API is not finding any result. I had the same problem.

```
function someFunction () {
    // some code here
    return "something";
}
```